# Process Memory increase WPF application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, memory, syncfusion

I'm creating a WPF program for editing PowerPoint presentation using Syncfusion library but whenever I run the program I see the memory increase when navigating from a page to another. I'm using WPF Application with a window that navigates between multiple pages.

How to encounter this problem actually?

Thank you.

These photos show where the leak is located :

[image: Leak1]

[image: Leak2]

[image: Leak3]

**PS:** Please focus on the InitializeNonUITasks method in home.cs because that's where the leak is.

**Home Page XAML:**

```
<Page x:Class="ProjectSABX.Pages.Home"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ProjectSABX.Pages"
  xmlns:syncfusion="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.Windows;assembly=Syncfusion.Shared.Wpf"
  xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
  mc:Ignorable="d"
  Width="1175" Height="660" KeyDown="Window_KeyDown"
  Title="Home">
<Grid ShowGridLines="False" Margin="2,-2,-2,2">
    <Grid Grid.Row="0" ShowGridLines="False">
        <Grid.Background>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="White" Opacity="0.5" />
        </Grid.Background>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="2.5*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Rectangle Height="52" Grid.Row="0"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Fill="#FF80A20D"></Rectangle>
        <TextBlock Name="titleBarTextBlock" Text="Aperçu" Height="40" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontWeight="Normal" Padding="15" FontSize="17.75"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="0"  HorizontalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0 15 10 0" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0">
        </StackPanel>
        <Image Source="/Images/ViewerIcons/ppt__logo for header.png" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="15" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="30"></Image>
    </Grid>

    <Grid Grid.Row="1" ShowGridLines="False">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="0*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="445*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="59*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="8*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Border ClipToBounds="True" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness=".7" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan ="3" Margin="0,51,3,0">
            <ScrollViewer Name="scrollViewer" Focusable="False" CanContentScroll="False" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan ="3">
                <Grid ShowGridLines="False">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="9*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <StackPanel Name="stackpanel" Grid.Column="1" Width="170" />
                </Grid>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Border>

        <Image Name ="centerSlideImage" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,57,5,19" />

        <Canvas Name="loadingIndicatorCanvas" Visibility="Collapsed" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="-250,-100,0,0">
            <Canvas Canvas.Left="21.75" Canvas.Top="14" Height="81.302" Width="80.197">
                <Canvas.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="Ellipse">
                        <Setter Property="Width" Value="5" />
                        <Setter Property="Height" Value="5" />
                        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="#FF9BD226" />
                    </Style>
                </Canvas.Resources>

                <Ellipse x:Name="_00" Canvas.Left="24.75" Canvas.Top="50" />
                <Ellipse x:Name="_01" Canvas.Top="36" Canvas.Left="29.5" />
                <Ellipse x:Name="_02" Canvas.Left="43.5" Canvas.Top="29.75" />
                <Ellipse x:Name="_03" Canvas.Left="57.75" Canvas.Top="35.75" />
                <Ellipse x:Name="_04" Canvas.Left="63.5" Canvas.Top="49.75" />
                <Ellipse x:Name="_05" Canvas.Left="57.75" Canvas.Top="63.5" />
                <Ellipse x:Name="_06" Canvas.Left="43.75" Canvas.Top="68.75" />
                <Ellipse x:Name="_07" Canvas.Top="63.25" Canvas.Left="30" />
                <Ellipse Stroke="{x:Null}" Width="39.5" Height="39.5" Canvas.Left="31.75" Canvas.Top="37" Fill="{x:Null}" />
            </Canvas>
        </Canvas>

        <Grid Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" ShowGridLines="False" Margin="0, -10">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="0.5*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="20*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="10*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="42*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="45*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="44*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="45*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="238*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="30*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="40*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="46*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="30*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="45*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Image Name="openDocument" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Height="30" Width="30" Source="/Images/ViewerIcons/ppt__open.png" MouseDown="openDocument_MouseDown" MouseEnter="openDocument_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="openDocument_MouseLeave" Margin="0,5,7,4"></Image>
            <Image Name="createPdfDocument" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" Height="30" Width="30" Source="/Images/ViewerIcons/ppt_pdf.png" MouseDown="createPdfDocument_MouseDown" MouseEnter="createPdfDocument_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="createPdfDocument_MouseLeave" Margin="0,5,8,4"></Image>
            <DockPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="6" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
                <Image Name="prevDocument"  Height="30" Width="30" Source="/Images/ViewerIcons/ppt__back.png" MouseDown="prevDocument_MouseDown" MouseEnter="prevDocument_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="prevDocument_MouseLeave"></Image>
                <Label Name="lblPageDisplay" Height="30" MinWidth="30" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="18" VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Padding="35,0,0,0" Foreground="#646464" />
                <Image Name="NextDocumentIconImage" Height="30" Width="30" Source="/Images/ViewerIcons/ppt__for.png"  MouseDown="NextDocument_MouseDown" MouseEnter="NextDocument_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="NextDocument_MouseLeave" Margin="-10,0"></Image>
            </DockPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

**Home Page C#:**

```
    public Home()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        pdfBackroundWorker.DoWork += pdfBackroundWorker_DoWork;
        pdfBackroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += pdfBackroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted;
        this.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(244, 244, 244));
        filePath = "/Data/Template.pptx";
        
        InitializeNonUITasks();
        InitializeUITasks(filePath);
        

    }

        
    private void openDocument_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
        dlg.Filter = "PowerPoint Presentations|*.pptx";
        Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();
        if (result == true)
        {
            string filename = dlg.FileName;
            filePath = filename;
            slideNumber = 1;
            displayBackroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
    }
    private void InitializeNonUITasks()
    {
        try
        {
            presentation = Presentation.Open(filePath);
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("This PowerPoint Presentation cannot be opened properly, please contact support");
            return;
        }
        slideImageSources.Clear();
        thumbnailImageSource.Clear();
        printImages.Clear();
        currentSlideNumber = 0;
        presentation.ChartToImageConverter = new ChartToImageConverter();
        presentation.ChartToImageConverter.ScalingMode = Syncfusion.OfficeChart.ScalingMode.Best;
        try
        {
            foreach (ISlide slide in presentation.Slides)
            {
                using (System.Drawing.Image image = slide.ConvertToImage(Syncfusion.Drawing.ImageType.Bitmap))
                {
                    System.Drawing.Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort myCallback = new System.Drawing.Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort(ThumbnailCallback);
                    printImages.Add(image.Clone() as System.Drawing.Image);
                    System.Drawing.Image newImage = image.GetThumbnailImage(170, 100, myCallback, System.IntPtr.Zero);
                    using (Stream ms = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        newImage.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                        var decoder = BitmapDecoder.Create(ms, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
                        thumbnailImageSource.Add(decoder.Frames[0]);
                    }

                    using (Stream ms = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                        var decoder = BitmapDecoder.Create(ms, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
                        slideImageSources.Add(decoder.Frames[0]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("This PowerPoint Presentation cannot be converted to images properly, please contact support");
            return;
        }
    }
```

**MainWindow XAML:**

```
<Frame Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" x:Name="Main" Source="./Pages/Home.xaml">
        <Frame.Background>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="#FFB0B0B0" Opacity="0.49" />
        </Frame.Background>
    </Frame>
```

**MainWindow.cs:**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        DataContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void ButtonClickHomePage(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Main.Content = new Home();
    }
 }
```

**Edit1:** I tried to use the dispose() method for each object that implemented IDisposable, When navigating at first, the memory process decreases. then when I navigate from page to page it increases again.

[image: Leak4]

[image: Leak5]

[image: Leak6]

[image: Leak7]

Comment: Could you please elaborate further, I didn't catch you.

Comment: It might be the `MemoryStream` objects according to the memory profile, not sure how/why this happens though. It's implementing the `IDisposable` interface and used in a `using` statement so it should be disposed after that. The snapshot still shows a low memory usage (13MB for memory stream for example), can you share a later snapshot?

Comment: @asaf92 I added snapshots that includes the moment I started the application, navigate between the home page and other pages at first, then going back to home page and re-navigating multiple time again

Comment: Due to snapshots information, even biggest memory consumers consume a quite few megabytes. Does you profiler displays managed or total memory consumption on "Process Memory (GB)" chart?
So the general recommendation would be - find object which take Gigabytes of RAM and look why are they held in the memory, and should they or not.

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to pinpoint the issue like this, but I do have some suggestions:

Usually it's about calling `Dispose` on all objects that implement the `IDisposable` interface.

- check all object for the `IDisposable` interface and call `Dispose()` if it's available. E.g.: newImage.Dispose() (or use `using`)
- Also, all the disposable objects in the lists `printImages`, `thumbnailImageSource` etc, should be disposed as well.
- Also, I believe the `decoder` should be disposed as well, as well as the `presentation`, although I can be mistaken.

---

This will give you a good starting point - there might be more, but you should rule out and fix this first.

The loop is a likely suspect to be causing the memory increase.

Here's more info on [IDisposable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.idisposable?view=netcore-3.1). Also, if you have implemented the `IDisposable` interface yourself - it's prety common to make a mistake with that as well. In that case you should double check it.